# Best word to use after at end of a sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

> "The excitement in the building was _________"

I'm trying to describe the excitement in building before a concert starts. What word would be the most suitable for this?

Comment: Check this link http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=excitement&typeofrhyme=jjb&loc=morejjb

Comment: And what is it *about* the excitement that you're trying to describe?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. There are many adjectives that could fill in the blank. Could you provide some adjectives that were close to what you wanted? And perhaps some that didn't,and why?

Answer (score 1):

As a [Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=palpable+excitement%2Ctangible+excitement%2Cexcitement+was+palpable%2Cexcitement+was+tangible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpalpable%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctangible%20excitement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcitement%20was%20palpable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcitement%20was%20tangible%3B%2Cc0) shows, a common collocation with *excitement* is the adjective *palpable*.  The synonym *tangible* also occurs, but with less frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[**Tangible**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tangible)

From Collins (via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tangible)):

> 1. capable of being touched or felt; having real substance: a tangible object.
> 2. capable of being clearly grasped by the mind; substantial rather than imaginary: tangible evidence.

The implication being that there was so much excitement, people could physically feel it. I've seen the phrase ["tangible excitement"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tangible+excitement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctangible%20excitement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctangible%20excitement%3B%2Cc0) in common usage.